# How much it costs to buy a mini-computer's schematics?

Tags: computer-architecture, buying

I think nowadays many of companies buy a design(schematics) of a board and only build it physically! I want to know, if I wanna buy a mini-computers information to build it, how much it will cost? something like raspberry pi for example!

Or maybe some cheaper boards like a USB flash memory information to build!

Are there any reputable companies to order or ask the prices?

I'm going to mass production of a robot that uses a mini computer. I thought it will be cheaper if I produce my boards too.

Comment: You generally do not buy a datasheet, you will get it for free when you buy the processor. The RPi uses a Qualcomm processor, you cannot buy those as an individual. You can buy development kits for many processors. Building a RPi like computer on your own when you have little experience is not something I would recommend anyway.

Comment: Broadcom, not Qualcomm, and the schematics are partial; it's not full OSHW.

Comment: @Pete: Interesting! but are those information really enough to build it? I think the problems will appear when you want to convert schematics to pcb!

Comment: @Hasani -- all due respect but problems are already appearing, you might just not be able to see them yet. IMO you're trying to take too large of a step. Namely, if you want to cheapen the production of "mass produced" robots by buying schematics and building the boards by yourself, you are skipping *a lot* of steps.

Comment: I pretty much agree with @WesleyLee here. I was planning on saying more until I read what he wrote. Bottom line? Solve your robot design problems first, using as much COTS as you can to get a proof of concept. Then see if you can sell them, at all. If you can, squeeze out costs as you grow your market. Eventually, you may decide the "mini" computer is next on your target list. But that's a ways out, I suspect. (Unless you have told us a lot less than you should have about where you are at right now.)

Comment: What kind of "mini-computer" do you have in mind? Which processor family do you plan to use?

Comment: Thank you guys, my robot prototype is made of this board: http://www.friendlyarm.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=109

And I have the market to selling thousands of them, so interested to ask that question.

Comment: Based on the title I seriously thought for a moment that this question related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minicomputer

Comment: @PeteBecker RPi is most definitely _not_ open source hardware! The Raspberry Pi Foundation has released partial schematics for their boards, but this does not make the design open source.

Comment: @duskwuff - thanks, I jumped to an invalid conclusion. I've deleted my incorrect comment.

Comment: @Hasani Contact the manufacturer of the board you want thousands of - I am sure they will be able to give you a good price. For that many boards, you may be able to get some customisation in the price if you ask nicely, like pre-programming or your logo on the silkscreen or some slightly-higher-quality component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right term is "schematic" to build from - a "datasheet" describes the function of something without including enough information to build it.

Generally they *aren't* available to just buy, legally. You may be able to go to Shenzen and buy pirate copies if you know the right people. Alternatively, some companies have what they call "reference designs": if you contact the processor manufacturer they can supply you with a schematic that will work, but you're expected to customise it a bit for your purposes.

Note also that building *one* of something which is normally made in the quantity of hundreds of thousands is usually very expensive.

Comment: Thanks for correction. 
I'm going to mass production of a robot that uses a mini computer. I thought it will be cheaper if I produce my boards too

Comment: @Hasani it almost certainly will not. Why would it? Let someone who's an expert in producing cheap computers build a cheap computer, and use that mass product. You'd get something that you wouldn't have to pay alone for R&D, testing, manufacture setup, quality control, supply stock,… Really, what you're trying to do will increase the price, not decrease it.

Answer (score 1):

The [schematics for the Raspberry Pi are available](https://web.archive.org/web/20160305080241/https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/Raspberry-Pi-Rev-2.1-Model-AB-Schematics.pdf) at raspberrypi.org.
The challenge is to find a source for the parts.

For incorporating a computer such as this into a product, I have heard that it is easier to use a [Beagleboard](https://beagleboard.org/) design such as the schematic for [Beaglebone Black](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CircuitCo/BeagleBone-Black/master/BBB_SCH.pdf). The information needed to build a Beaglebone Black is freely available, and you might be able to find sources for the parts.

Comment: So, it means if I had a PCB product line, I could build it? there is no more information needed to build?

Comment: I think the goal of the BeagleBone black is to provide all the necessary information. I have not verified whether or not they have met this goal. Also, managing PC board assembly requires expertise in electronics and manufacturing. There are always issues that come up, and technical decisions to be made. Based on your questions, I think you will also need help from someone with more experience.